facing "Unable to serve request" error while running the advancedio function from the Catalyst CLI using the command catalyst serve
I have a Zoho Catalyst advanced-io function. When I try to test it on my local machine, I am getting "Unable to reach server" and "Unable to serve request" kind of errors.
What am I doing wrong here?

You might face this issue if you are trying to serve the function from inside your function directory. You can navigate back to your project directory (where your catalyst.json file is present), and then run the catalyst serve command.
Also, you can overcome this issue by updating your Catalyst CLI to its latest version by running the command npm i -g zcatalyst-cli by using sudo command if you are using Linux/Mac and using command prompt administrator mode if you are using Windows.
